# Circle packing 2nd column distance from left side of square

Tags: geometry, circles, packing-problem

Do I have it right that the top circle in the 2nd-column to the right of the below packed square is $r(\sqrt{3}+1)$ units to the right of the left edge of the square. And by "is" I mean where the top circle in the 2nd-column kisses the top of the square:

[image]

Here, $r = 0.111382s$, where $s$ is the length of the square's side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can draw equilateral triangles between the centers of the circles.  The first column is $r$ to the left of the right edge.  The equilateral triangles have side $2r$ so height $r\sqrt 3$, making the second row of centers $r(1+\sqrt 3)$ in.

The above answer was based on the assumption that the circles are close packed, which results in the bounding box being a rectangle, not a square.  The statement $r \approx 0.111382s$ comes from [packomania](http://www.packomania.com/) where they are finding the largest circle for which you can fit (here) $20$ in a square.  The bounding box for close packed circles is $(8+\frac 12\sqrt 3)r \approx 8.866r$ tall and $(2+4\sqrt 3)r \approx 8.928r$ wide.  The sides are moved in a bit and the circles spread vertically to make the box a square.  The side becomes about $8.978r$.  You won't see the differences in wood.  I wonder if there is a typo in the packomania figure.  I would have expected the side to be between $8.866r$ and $8.928r$.  We should be able to fit $20$ close packed in $8.928r$ with vertical room to spare.

Comment: Thank you. This packing is saving me a lot on wood. Can't seem to work out how WolframAlpha got "0.111382" for the search "pack 20 circles in a square."

Comment: The "0.111382" figure suggests that there are less than 9 radii stacked in a column, which means that, "microscopically," they are not, in fact, touching. There are infinitesimal spaces between them. I don't know why that bothers me.

Comment: I think the orange color on the diagram on packomania reflects the fact that the circles are not symmetrically constrained, but I didn't find an explanation.  The purple ones in other packings are free to move at least a little bit.